# Function that returns the numbers of subintervals?

Tags: r

I'm trying create a function that the user enters with a vector (file) and the function returns the number of subintervals possible of differents sizes without exceeding the dimensions of the vector. The function has worked well for many values, but for some specific values has exceeded the dimensions and i don't know why. Follows the reproducible example, note that when *box_size = 101* (size of subintervals) them the function returns *ninbox = 5* (number of subintervals) and not *4* how should be.

```
file = rnorm(500);N<-length(file)

box_size <-c(92,101,111)

j=1;ninbox2<-0;aux_ninbox<-0;aux_ninbox[1]<-box_size[j];ninbox<-0;sum_box<-0

for(j in 1:length(box_size)){

  while(aux_ninbox<=N){

    ninbox<-ninbox+1
    sum_box[ninbox]<- box_size[j]
    aux_ninbox<-sum_box[ninbox]+ aux_ninbox
    ninbox2[j]<-ninbox

    } 

  aux_ninbox<-0;aux_ninbox[1]<-box_size[j];ninbox<-0;sum_box<-0
}

ninbox2
```

For instance, if the size of the subinterval is *101* and the size of the vector is *500*, them the function count how many subintervals of size *101* fit in *500*. In this case, 101+101+101+101 = 404 (4 subintervals) because the next exceeding the dimension of the vector (*500*). This function have an error, because is returning *5* for intervals of size *101*. But note that for intervals of size *92* and *111* is working perfectly!

Comment: Excuse me, but please try to explain again, what your code should do. And perhaps a more simple example as shown above, I don't think we need 32 boxes.

Comment: Ok Martin, i did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now I get it. I simplified your code a little bit:

```r
file <- rnorm(500)
N <- length(file)

box_size <- c(92,101,111)

ninbox2 <- 0

for (j in 1:length(box_size)){
  aux_ninbox <- box_size[j]
  ninbox <- 0
  sum_box <- 0

  while (aux_ninbox<=N){
    ninbox <- ninbox+1
    sum_box[ninbox] <- box_size[j]
    aux_ninbox <- sum_box[ninbox]+ aux_ninbox
    ninbox2[j] <- ninbox
  } 

}

ninbox2
```

There were a few issues when your variables were declared:

```r
aux_ninbox[1] <- box_size[j]
```

should not be assigned at the end of your `for`-loop. You have to put it at the beginning, before the `while`-loop starts. That caused your error, since the second iteration of you `for`-loop again used the box_size of 92 for the calculation.

If you just want to get the number of boxes, you could simply use

```r
N %/% box_size
```

This divides the length of your given vector by the sizes of your boxes ignoring the rests. See "Arithmetic Operators" in R help for more information about `div` and `mod`.